# What is meant by property in java ?

Tags: java

Does it differ from methods? Like arrays have a property - length and so array.length gives the length of array whereas array.length() gives an error

Comment: It kind of depends on context. You can describe and object as having "properties" which define it, which are typically represent via getter and (optional) setter methods, but not always the case (as you've described).  Generally, when talking about "properties" you are talking about the abstract functionality and information of the object, not necessarily the means by which that functionality is implemented.  For example, a `JTextField` has a `text` property, which is implemented via the `get/setText` methods

Comment: yes a `field` is not the same as a `method`

Comment: There's no such thing as a "property" in the Java Language Specification, it's an informal word.

Comment: In Java you mostly use the word `property` (or `properties`) for persistent properties (read about it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties).

Answer (score 6):

A better term to use for properties is a field. Basically, a field is a variable, while a method is where you have the "meat" of your code. For these examples, I'll be using the object "Book".

Fields can be classified as "instance" variables meaning that they are different for each object, or they can be classified as "static" variables, which means that they are universal for the project.

```
private int pages;
private static int amountOfBooksInTheWorld;
```

The number of pages is specific to a certain book, a specific "instance" of the book object. The amount of books in the world is obviously not specific to one book; therefore, it is "static", universal, for all books. Instance variables are called by stating objectname.variablename, while static variables are called by classname.variablename.

```
javahandbook.pages
Book.amountOfBooksInTheWorld
```

Now for your second question, methods, those things with the parentheses, are usually classified into these groups: constructor, accessor, mutator, and static methods. All methods have "parameters" and "return types". The parameters are basically inputs. The return types are the outputs (if there are any). Methods are called by objectname.method(), unless they are static, where they are called by classname.method().

Constructors are what you use to create your object. They usually are the ones which "initialize" all the instance variables for the object, that is to say, they basically tell them what they start as. These methods have no return type. Constructors are probably the most different method type from the rest, but are very important.

```
public Book(int p) {
    pages = p; //We use "=" to initialize our variables (left becomes the right)
}
```

In action...

```
Book javahandbook = new Book(100); //A new book has been created!
```

Accessor methods are what other classes use to find out what are the instance variables of a particular object. These specify a return type of either boolean (a fancy name for true or false), floating point numbers (double-precise return types that include double and float), regular numbers (integer return types such as byte, short, int, or long), or even other objects. The return type is what you get "back" when the method is done doing its thing. Keep in mind that the object being referred to in the method call is the "implicit parameter", meaning that it can be referred to using "this". It sounds wierd. I'll show you an example.

```
public int getPages() {
    return (this.pages);
}
```

In action...

```
int test = javahandbook.getPages();
System.out.println(test); //This will return the amount of pages
//Note that what I did with the 2nd line was bad coding practice, but it works in this scenario
```

Mutator methods change the instance variables. Their return type is "void".

```
public void ripPages(int rippedpages) {
    this.pages = this.pages - rippedpages;
    System.out.println("HULK SMASH");
}
```

In action...

```
javahandbook.ripPages(300);
```

Static methods are the ones that are universal, not on a per object basis. They can have any return type.

```
public static int countBooks(List<Book> books) {
    return (books.size);
}
```

In action...

```
public int howmanybooksinthislist = Book.countBooks;
```

Put all of them together and you get...

```
public class Book {
    private int pages;
    private static int amountOfBooksInTheWorld;
    public Book(int p) {
       pages = p;
    }
    public int getPages() {
        return (this.pages);
    }
    public void ripPages(int rippedpages) {
        this.pages = this.pages - rippedpages;
        System.out.println("HULK SMASH");
    }
    public static int countBooks(List<Book> books) {
    return (books.size);
}
```

I know this was a bit too lengthy, but I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

Properties/Fields are variables in a class. For example:

```
public class Employee {
  private String name;
  private int salary;
  public getName(){return this.name};
}
```

In the class above, `name` and `salary` are properties of an instance of the class (object of the class) while `getName()` is a method.

Answer (score 1):

Properties are the adjectives describing an object, in this example "how many elements it has". Properties are set to define variable aspects of instance of the object, either directly (if allowed) or as the result of some action, and then they may be examined when using the object.

Methods are the verbs provided to do something with the object, for example "add a new element". These actions may utilize properties, and may alter them, as well as doing other things (whatever purpose the creator defines). Methods may also accept adverbs in the parenthesis that further effect how they operate, thus the different syntax with "()"; for example information to "add in the new element".

While methods are more complex and versatile mechanisms, a complex object might not have pre-calculated (cached) "x.length" type properties always already available to examine and thus the object might provide a method "x.length()" to get the information. That method might have to evaluate complex aspects of an object to figure out "length", and either set it and or give it back, blurring the line between a property and that more simple use of a method.

Tangent on "field", "property" and "properties": while the technical term "field" very specifically identifies a data storage element attached to an object, the term "property" is acknowledged by the core group at  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/information/glossary.html. A property is more abstract, but logically synonymous to field when considered in comparison to a method. Logically different than field/property in this comparison, though related, is a "properties" set which is a static gathering of initial settings of property values for an application (a collection of code presented for a designated use), most often placed in a file ".properties" named and stored at a location agreed upon by the application - though these might also be gathered in any other storage location like a database.

Answer (score 0):

array.length is accessing a field inside the object, while array.length() is attempting call a method call length(), and since the method does not exist, it gives an error

Answer (score 0):

To understand properties and methods, think of an apple. An apple can be different colours, like red, yellow, etc. An apple can also have varying sizes. Both of these traits, colour and size, are `properties` of an individual apple; they describe the apple.

A method is different. It describes something an apple can **do**, like grow and ripen. Some methods, however, can also represent properties, and simplify reading those properties.

For example, an object representing a pen might have a certain amount of ink left. When requesting how much ink is left, the pen object would need to verify that there is any, and refill the pen if not, before returning how much ink there is.

To directly answer your question, properties and methods are very different. Properties hold data about an object, but methods hold data about what an object can do. Something like the length of an array is a property because it describes the array itself, not what the array can do.

This and other definitions of some useful terms are given [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/information/glossary.html).